# How does $e^{\frac{\ln(t)}{4}} = t^{\frac14}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$e^{\frac{\ln(t)}{4}} =e^{\ln(4)} \cdot e^{\frac14} = t^4\cdot e^{\frac14}$$

But $t^4 \cdot e^{\frac14} \neq t^{\frac14}$, so why is the answer $t^{\frac14}$?

Comment: How do you go from $e^{\ln (t)/4}$ to $e^{\ln 4}\cdot e^{1/4}$ (???) and to $t^4e^{1/4}$?

Comment: You don't have $e^{ab}=e^a.e^b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $t>0$. Then,
\begin{align}
e^{\frac{\ln(t)}{4}} &= e^{\ln(t^{1/4})} = t^{\frac{1}{4}}.
\end{align}

Also, your first equality is false. The correct rule is $e^{\alpha + \beta} = e^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\beta}$, NOT $e^{\alpha \beta} = e^{\alpha} e^{\beta}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note: $x^{a + b} = x^a \times x^b$

then

$\mathrm{Apply\:log\:rule}:\quad \:a^{\log _a\left(b\right)}=b$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^{\frac{\ln t}{4}}\quad \forall \ \ x>0$

Taking logarithms on both sides,

$$\ln x=\ln e^{\frac{\ln t}{4}}$$
$$\ln x=\frac{\ln t}{4}\ln e$$
$$\ln x=\frac{\ln t}{4}$$
$$\ln x=\ln t^{1/4}$$
$$x=t^{1/4}$$
$$\therefore e^{\frac{\ln t}{4}}=t^{1/4} $$

Comment: In your first line, i think you mean $t>0$. Your argument is valid.

Comment: $\ln t$ in the question simply shows that $t>0$. I assumed $x>0$ in first line to validate $\ln x$

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the rules of powers (indices).

The correct rule is $x^{a+b} = x^ax^b$.

But the rule you need to use here is $x^{ab} = (x^a)^b = (x^b)^a$

So here, $e^{\frac{\ln t}{4}} = e^{\ln t \cdot \frac 14} = (e^{\ln t})^{\frac 14} = t^{\frac 14}$.

In the last step, we apply $e^{\ln x} = x$ in the simplification.

Note that you can also equivalently write $e^{\frac{\ln t}{4}} = e^{\ln t \cdot \frac 14} = (e^{\frac 14})^{\ln t}$ but that's not very useful since you can't simplify further.